# Need to format a set of float variables to 00.00

Tags: java, jsp

Ok so I have a database colum 'UnitPrice' with a range of values 
example: 23, 23.5, 43.23

Now I need to know if there is a way to format them all to the 00.00 format when printing them out. I've been failing at this for about an hour now...

Comment: Using floating-point data types such as `float` or `double` for money (you mention 'UnitPrice') is a bad idea. I hope this is not for a real piece of production-ready software...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [format api](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html) in jdk.

Answer (score 2):

You normally use the [JSTL](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) [`fmt`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/tld-summary.html) taglib for this. This way you don't need to hassle with this in the business layer, but in the view layer, there where it belongs.

To install JSTL, just drop [jstl-1.2.jar](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar) in `/WEB-INF/lib` and to use the `fmt` taglib, just declare it in top of JSP as per [its documentation](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/tld-summary.html).

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
```

Then you can use [`fmt:formatNumber`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatNumber.html) to format the doubles the way you want, here's an example with euro:

```
<p>The price is: <fmt:formatNumber value="${unit.price}" type="currency" currencySymbol="&euro;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("00.00");
Double[] array = new Double[] {23d, 23.5d, 43.23d};
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(array[i]));
}
```

or using format/printf syntax:

```
Double[] array = new Double[] {23d, 23.5d, 43.23d};
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    System.out.format("%05.2f\n", array[i]);
}
```